# flutter audio_service not playing audio

Tags: android, flutter

So I have followed the tutorial https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/wiki/Tutorial

However I have not had any success getting it to work.
My first issues was
`final _completer = Completer();`
Their is no Completer class so that throw an error.

And it seems that the code they provide just does not fire the following class.

```
/*AUDIO PLAYER*/
class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  final _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
 // final _completer = Completer();

  @override
  Future<void> onStart(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
    // Connect to the URL
    print("test");

    await _audioPlayer.setUrl("https://perth.adstichr.com.au/station/DRN1?uuid=0000-0000-0000-0000");
    // Now we're ready to play
    _audioPlayer.play();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onStop() async {
    // Stop playing audio
    await _audioPlayer.stop();
    // Shut down this background task
    await super.onStop();
  }
}
```

The full code is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Example',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: AudioServiceWidget(child: MainScreen()),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Example")),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            RaisedButton(child: Text("Start"), onPressed: start),
            RaisedButton(child: Text("Stop"), onPressed: stop),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  start() =>
      AudioService.start(backgroundTaskEntrypoint: _backgroundTaskEntrypoint);

  stop() => AudioService.stop();


  _backgroundTaskEntrypoint() {
    AudioServiceBackground.run(() => AudioPlayerTask());
  }

}



/*AUDIO PLAYER*/
class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  final _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  // final _completer = Completer();

  @override
  Future<void> onStart(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
    // Connect to the URL
    print("test");

    await _audioPlayer.setUrl("https://perth.adstichr.com.au/station/DRN1?uuid=0000-0000-0000-0000");
    // Now we're ready to play
    _audioPlayer.play();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onStop() async {
    // Stop playing audio
    await _audioPlayer.stop();
    // Shut down this background task
    await super.onStop();
  }
}
```

Comment: `Completer` should be the class from `dart:async` library. Did you import it?

Comment: @JigarPatel i have since your comment but the example code still does not play

Comment: I was testing the code and apparently AudioService.start() returns false. I am not quite sure why is that but perhaps this helps you in finding the issue

Comment: @naif.mazen so I take it this is a big with their code?

Comment: perhaps, looking at the code of the package I see that it returns false based on a boolean called _running and if ui.PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle(backgroundTaskEntrypoint) returns null
so I am not really sure if its an issue with their code or not

Comment: for the issue with completer you need to import this
import 'dart:async';

Answer (score 2):

I followed the document we must add the method **_backgroundTaskEntrypoint()** on the top level function, so you should move the function outside the class.

```
// Must be a top-level function
void _backgroundTaskEntrypoint() {
   AudioServiceBackground.run(() => AudioPlayerTask());
}

/*AUDIO PLAYER*/
class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  final _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  ...
}
```

Comment: this is a usefull link tutorial https://itnext.io/create-an-awesome-background-running-music-player-like-amazon-music-in-flutter-341a59efa936

Answer (score 0):

It's not working for me either.  Note that to use audio_service on Android you must put the following lines into AndroidManifest.xml.  However, when I do so, com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver gives an error "Class referenced in the manifest, com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService, was not found in the project or the libraries", and I'm not sure what to do about that.

This needs to go into the Manifest.  See the documentation.

```
<manifest ...>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

  <application ...>

    ...

    <service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver> 
  </application>
</manifest>
```